# Data extraction from the database using ResultSetExtractor or RowMapper

Tags: hsqldb, resultset, jdbctemplate

I have a probelem with the data extraction from the database. I have following tables in my database

TABLE USER, attributes ID and USERNAME, 
e.g.

```
[ ID | USERNAME ]
[ 1  | John     ]
[ 2  | Jane     ]
```

TABLE FRUIT, attributes FRUITID and NAME,
e.g.

```
[ FRUITID | NAME     ]
[ 1       | Apple    ]
[ 2       | Pear     ]
```

TABLE CONSUMATION, attributes UID references USER.ID, FID references FRUIT.FRUITID and QUANTITY, PRIMARY KEY (uid, fid),
e.g.

```
[ UID | FID | QUANTITY ]
[ 1   |  1  | 1        ]
[ 1   |  2  | 2        ]
[ 2   |  1  | 1        ]
```

Model User which I am trying to extract from the database

```
public class User {

private int userId;
private String userName;
private Map<Fruit, Integer> fruits;

public User() {
    fruits = new HashMap<Fruit, Integer>();
}

public User(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
    fruits = new HashMap<Fruit, Integer>();
}

public User(int userId, String userName) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userName = userName;
    fruits = new HashMap<Fruit, Integer>();
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public Map<Fruit, Integer> getFruits() {
    return fruits;
}

public void setFruits(Map<Fruit, Integer> fruits) {
    this.fruits = fruits;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
}
```

I use this query to select the data from the database

```
SELECT * FROM USERS U LEFT JOIN CONSUMATION C ON (U.ID = C.UID)
```

and after I execute it i get these values, like on the image below
http://s30.postimg.org/4bbu3q9oh/image.png

For each user there should be created one object and it's consumation values should be saved in his map. e.g.

```
USER: ID:1 USERNAME: "Amer"    FRUITS: (FRUITID: 1 Q:1); (FRUITID 2 Q:2)
USER: ID:2 USERNAME: "Nina"    FRUITS: (FRUITID: 3 Q:2)
USER: ID:3 USERNAME: "Viktor"  FRUITS:
```

I am using Spring JdbcTemplate and this is what I have tried so far. Unfortunately, it didn't work...

```
@Component
public class UserDaoImpl {

private DataSource dataSource;

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public User getUser(int userId) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE id = ?";
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {userId}, new UserMapper());
}

public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS U LEFT JOIN CONSUMATION C ON (U.ID = C.UID)";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new MyUserExtractor());
}

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

private static final class UserMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(resultSet.getInt("ID"));
        user.setUserName(resultSet.getString("USERNAME"));
        return user;
    }

}

private static final class MyUserExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor {

    @Override
    public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
    DataAccessException {
        ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            User user = new User();

            HashMap<Fruit, Integer> fruits = new HashMap<Fruit, Integer>();
            user.setUserId(rs.getInt("ID"));
            user.setUserName(rs.getString("USERNAME"));
            fruits.put(new Fruit(rs.getInt("FID")), rs.getInt("QUANTITY"));
            user.setFruits(fruits);
            users.add(user);
        }                       
        return users;
    }
}

}
```

so how would it be possible to achieve this? I'll appreciate any help
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what does not work specifically. In general, the flow and the usage of ResultSetExtractor is correct. What I can see is that you do not aggregate users - continue creating the new User for each row in the result set. For this, you could just use RowMapper. But if you use ResultSetExtractor to create single row per user, you need always to check if your list already contains the user and update only his fruits map with the new fruit, rather than creating new user.